# How do I procedurally spread a number of circles across the sides of a bigger one?

Tags: node-editor, procedural, compositing-nodes

For a client project, I need to spread small filled circles across a bigger circle in a procedural way, do you have any idea on how to make this work? I am asking since I don't have any idea of how to get a (vector?) curve into the compositor somehow. If you have any ideas, please let me know.

[image: Example]

Comment: Can the downvoter give some indication of what the issue is and how to resolve?

Comment: Why does this need to be constructed in the compositor? Can you create your mask in geometry, or a shader?

Comment: First of all, welcome to BSE, Linus. @AllenSimpson FWIW am an advocate that we own our votes _eg_ who  voted  listed in question activity.    Personally don't find this question worthy of a vote either way. If (and only if) I had to choose one, it would  be a DV (Reason: Mouse over the DV button:  _"This question doesn't show any research effort"_) the often seen python q equivalent is `my_great_script_idea = YouWriteItForMe()`  The question text could be  "de fluffed" pretty much to title. Who cares? In the end it has joined the HNQ circus and currently  has 5 UVs, and two great answers....

Comment: Thanks @batFINGER.  I just had to assume this was in a review queue when I saw it, and it wasn't receiving any feedback.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes, this can be done in blender procedurally. You can build a node that can do that. Don't worry. Follow this.
First of all, you need to create a node that can be used to radially spread procedural objects across a circle.
First, add a texture coordinate node. Then add a vector math node, set it to subtract and enter 0.5 for all the values. Then add a gradient texture then set it to radial.
You should see this:

[image]

Now, add a multiply node and set it to 6. Then, add a snap node and set it to 1. You should see this:

[image]

What we now have are 6 sectors each with their own indices (0,1,2,3,4,5). Indices are those numbers that represent a specific sector, just like a name of someone represents a specific person. Now, we will use trigonometry to calculate the vectors that are in the middle of the sectors. Then, we will add or subtract that from the original generated coordinates of the texture coordinate node to create final coordinates per sector that we can use to instance circles across a circle! Don't worry if this looks complicated. Even  I don't get this 100% clear. But I just memorised the way you can make this. Lol.
Now, we need to find the x and y of these vectors that I have marked in blue:
[image]

As you may know, a vector is defined by an x and a y value. So how do we find those values using trigonometry?
We can say that the length / magnitude of our vectors is going to be 1. If I create a triangle like this:

[image]

The hypotenuse is 1 (because our vector's length is one).
Now, to find the x and y, we can use trigonometry. But we need to get the theta/angle that is in the middle. So add a math node, set it to divide, set the first value to (pi*2) and the second to 6 (because we have 6 sectors).

[image]
Then, add 0.5 to the snap (as we need the middle of the sectors so indices will now be 0.5,1.5,2.5,3.5,4.5 and 6.5) and multiply the divide and this add output like this using a multiply node:

[image]
Now we have found the theta.
Now, to get the Y of the vector, we can use "sine" function. Formula will be : sin (theta) = perpendicular/hypotenuse
sine(theta) = y/1
We can omit the "1" because it is the denominator. So sine(theta) will give us our Y.
[image]

So add a math node, set it to sine and you should have this:
[image]

To get the X, we can use cosine. cos(theta) = Base/hyp
cos(theta) = x/1 (remove the 1):
cos(theta) = x
So add a cosine node and do this:

[image]

Now, we have the x and y of our vectors but we need to combine them. So add a combine XYZ node and plug the sine into Y and cos into X like this:

[image]

Make sure you plug it in the correct order otherwise it might not work. Now add a vector math node and set it to add and add the original coordinates from the start like this:

[image]

[image]

Now add a vector math node and set it to scale. Add it here and set it to 5:

[image]

Now, you should have this:

[image]

Now, after the add node, add a vector math node and set it to length. The length node is used to create a circle:

[image]

Add a color ramp for final control:

[image]

To control the number of circles change the value of the number of sectors using the value node I added but didnt mention (sorry for that):

[image]

When value is at 12, you should get 12 circles:

[image]

Tada! Here you have it.

[image]

Comment: I know this looks very complicated but please don't worry about that. I myself keep most of my focus on the building part rather than the understanding part.

Answer (score 11):

**Just for fun...**

Thought maybe I can replace dreadful, forever hated trigonometry with a simple vector rotate, but in the end having to multiply the coords by `-1` (because radial texture starts on the left), or to offset half of the snap range to not cut the circle in half (or force using two coordinates as the middle of the first snap range isn't aligned with an axis) and things like that end up with node clutter.

The idea is simple, though, after snapping the radial texture, (un-)rotate the coordinate system to be in a triangle going left, and operate on that triangle - basically simulating a local coordinate system of some objects with various rotations.

[image]

[image]

Since this answer got too many upvotes, here's **Variant #2 for trigfans** - however, whatever I try, I end up with the same number of nodes...

[image]

[image]

Comment: Wow! This looks amazing!