# Shading - Circles array along concentric circles

Tags: node-editor, procedural

I am trying to figure out a way to do this but with shaders on a plane:

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/soQA0.png]

I found this post [How do I procedurally spread a number of circles across the sides of a bigger one?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/234725/how-do-i-procedurally-spread-a-number-of-circles-across-the-sides-of-a-bigger-on)
that manages to do that to one ring. But I need to have many rings and it should have more instances of circles when the rings have a bigger perimeter.

I guess it could be forced using the method from to post above, but that would require a lot of manual tweaking of values, and a ton of nodes, I know it must be a smart way to do it, but I am not that smart hehe...

Thanks for your time

Comment: The page in your link brings up a 404 (not found) error here.

Comment: sorry! Fixed now

Answer (score 6):

[image]

- Based on given parameters, calculate the nearest ring (of circles) towards the center, and the nearest ring towards the outside.
- Calculate the distance in the custom group to not repeat the same logic twice.
- Take the lesser distance ("Greater Than" node might be misleading here, but this way I cross links less).
- Now you have a voronoi-like distance, so without applying a threshold or color ramp etc. you would get this:

[image]

Custom Group:

[image]

- *Object* texture coordinate is hard-coded, which goes against good programming principles.
- Multiply the radius by $τ$ ($2πr$) to get circumference.
- Calculate how many circles will fit into the circumference by dividing it by the diameter. This is only an approximation but it's good enough.
- $1/n$umber of circles is a reciprocal telling you the subrange of the 0..1 range for each circle.
- Using "wrap" we can have that repeating subrange.
- Using "divide" $.5\over n$ and $-.5\over n$ instead of $1\over n$ offsets the range so it is signed (rotating in either of two ways, whichever is closer).
- Move towards the processed ring, and rotate towards the circle nearest on this ring.
- Calculate distance from obtained position to the original position.

[image]

Some parameters give weird results:

[image]

You can combat this with random rotations of the input vector, with seed based on the radius of the ring (so the entire ring gets consistent rotation offset):

[image]

Ultimately, the [pareidolia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pareidolia) will always make you see some patterns:

[image]

[image]

While working on the animation below, **I found a small bug in the above file**, the rotation should be inverted!

[image]

[image] [image] [image]

Comment: oh my... thank you so much for this answer! I am trying to replicate it on an object that is 8 by 8 cm and I can't make it work. The closest I got is to have control over the rings, but not to form the little circles, I will keep trying to find my mistake!

Comment: @Martín I uploaded .blend file, typically test stuff on the default plane - Texture Coordinate: Object relies on dimensions.

Comment: I noticed now, there are issues with those rotations, circles can be cut in halves. I was worried this might be an unreliable hack…

Comment: Great shader ... Thanks a lot :)

Comment: a m a z i n g ! truly, what a shader you made!

Answer (score 4):

### EDIT

*I forget to mention one **disadvantage** ... this technique requires subdivided plane ... it can be sub-div inside geo-nodes too, but for some some complex meshes it can be heavy to handle. The thing is the attribute (color) is transferred to vertices.*

---

If you don't mind you can use *Geometry Nodes* and use **Geometry Proximity** of generated points ...

With this node tree you can generate points directly for object...

[image]
[image]

as Attribute in Shader ...

[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: whaaaaaaat? That is amazing! thank you so much :) I'll use that!

Comment: I see you're adding some animations too :D

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady It was possible before too ... it is just more catchy :) I'm still running behind you ... GN version is in section of workaround (due the topology), than your proper way of shader. Don't worry :)

Comment: you guys rock! thanks a lot :D

Answer (score 3):

Here's a start at a more general 'Radial Tile' group, which divides the given texture-space into concentric rings of tiles around texture-0, each with their own UV.

[image]

It makes use of *Cartesian to Polar* and *Polar to Cartesian* subgroups. Most of the manipulation is of the space measured in polar coordinates.

Inputs:

- Overall scale
- Ring Density
- The number of cells in the innermost ring (which determines the outgoing pattern).

At the moment, it outputs

- Cartesian Cell UV (by default oriented with incoming UV)
- Cartesian Cell Center
- Cell Polar UV and Center, which can be used in other ways. (The Polar UV will deform mapped textures.)

Some effects:

[image]

It could do with a lot of  improvement I think. But .. just chucking it in in case it's useful in its current state.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to the party :)

Comment: you guys are so smart! I'll certainly write all of this down :O

Comment: I forgot to follow this thread, closing some old tabs (tab hoarder here) discovered this answer. Pretty cool: instead of solving my problem of patterns emerging it arranges circles in a nice pattern, especially with Inner Count 2..4. It looks like only Inner Count 2..3 the rings can touch, the Inner Count = 3 has a nice, tight packing of circles.

Comment: Thanks, @MarkusvonBroady! It's not quite good enough, yet, for me. I want 'distance from edge' and simpler  variable radial offset per ring, for paving patterns, tiles on conical roofs,  etc.